# What's wrong in this NSFetchRequest?

Tags: ios, ios5, core-data

Simple question. Could anyone tell me what's wrong with this piece of code?

```
+ (NSManagedObject*) managedObjectWithServerId:(NSInteger)serverId inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context{

    //Execute request and get all the results
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest * request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass(self)];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"serverId == %@" argumentArray:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:serverId]]];
    NSArray * results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
}
```

The results array is always an NSArray with 0 objects, no errors are given, nothing. Just a 0-count array.
And it's not possible to return always 0 elements, I am exploring the Core Data database with a SQLite explorer, and there are elements with the `serverId` I am requesting, so there should be at least 1.

Am I doing the predicate wrong?

The above code is implemented in an `NSManagedObject` category, and called as shown:

```
 [User managedObjectWithServerId:whatev inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Where `User` is an entity in my model and subclass of `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: I'm a little curious about two parts of your code. 1) What class is this method implemented in, and does its name match with an entity in your model? 2) Try a simpler predicate, e.g. `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"serverId = %@",@(serverId)]`, note the single equal sign. See if that does anything. Might just be superstition but who knows.

Comment: 1) It's implemented in a category of NSManagedObject. All the objects in my model need to have a the id of the object in the server (serverId). And I need to fetch the objects trough this serverId
2) Tried your code, and no luck, I still get 0 results :\

Maybe this extra info can help. Sometimes my app crashes with the core data auto-saving (not when I am performing the save manually, that works perfectly)

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores.  It cannot perform a save operation.'

Comment: now when you actually invoke the method you are doing it like `[AnEntityClass managedObjectWithServerId:inManagedObjectContext:]` and not calling directly on `NSManagedObject` right? Just checking. And that sounds bad about no persistent stores...

Comment: Yeah of course. For example, from the class User, I get it like [User managedObjectWithServerId:whatev inManagedObjectContext:context];

I checked the fetch request object and the class is correct. If it was incorrect I would get an error, and not 0 results. Maybe something about the context?

Comment: You can add "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3" to the launch arguments of your target, then all SQLite queries are shown in the debugger window. Then you can compare that with your SQLite explorer.

Comment: @Lupi I'm at a loss, sorry. Only thing I can think of is some issue with updating from the persistent store. Also, I did edit some facts from this thread into your question, hopefully that's OK.

Comment: I tried putting "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3" in the Schemes->Arguments section. No SQL output at all...
Tried deleting app->Clean proyect->Build & run. Same thing happens...
I am clueless... also the persistenStoreCoordinator thingy happens the second time I run the app, it's so confusing ._.

Comment: OK, I Found what happened.
Recently I encapsulated all the NSFileManager functionality in an external class. When I check if the database file existed, I was calling a method that check it's a normal file, but Core Data DB file is actually a directory.
Fixed it and now it works as it used to work, doesn't crash and I can see all the SQLite debug stuff.

Sorry for wasting your time >_<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed, it seems I was always re-creating the Database file because of an unexpected condition. I noticed because all the Primary Keys were always starting from 1.

CoreData seems to have some issues if you don't delete the previous UIManagedDocument Database file before creating the new one.

With the condition fixed, I get no NSPersistentStoreCoordinator crash error, I can see all the SQL methods with debugging and my fetches, of course, works correctly.

Thanks to all the people who tried helping, and sorry for wasting your time :)